# MinGW -- trying to use both stat() and <stdint.h>

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I'm using `MingGW` on a `W7x64` computer. At different parts in my program, I have to detect if a file is a directory, but I also have to use `uint32_t`.

I can't do the latter without using the `-std=c++11` flag, which seems to activate `_STRICT_ANSI_`. That variable makes me unable to use stat. (The declaration of the `struct` is in an `#ifndef _STRICT_ANSI_` block).

What should I do? Should I just assume certain sizes of integers, and forgo C++11, or is there a way around this mess?

Comment: "I can't do the latter without using the -std=c++11 flag" - why exactly is that? There is "cstdint" for c++11 mode, but there is still "stdint.h" without c++11, so what went wrong?

Comment: ...That worked. I have no idea why, but it did. Thanks! Why would cstdint be C++11 only, but stdint.h be in both?

Comment: Probably cstdint was not considered standardized enough at the time of C++03? I don't know for sure.

Comment: Can you just post a bit of your code?

Comment: The functional or non functional kind? Gassa's comment fixed the problem.